# The name of the document which prove my studies at the university

Tags: terminology

I am originally from one country but study at university in a different country. Now, my native country asked me to prove that I study at this university and I want to ask my university to bring me document for that. What is this document used to be called?

Can I call this document "study confirmation letter" or "confirmation of studies"?

I found ([here](http://www.cambridgestudents.cam.ac.uk/your-course/graduate-study/your-student-status/confirmation-study-verification-letters)) the phrase "proof of study" ans also "Certificate of Enrolment" ([here](https://www.stir.ac.uk/registry/studentinformation/confirmationdocuments/)), "proof of enrolment" ([here](http://www.southampton.ac.uk/studentservices/letter-requests/confirmation-of-study.page)) but "proof of study" as well as "confirmation for studies" both seems to be for those who are graduated already while I'm still student there. I would like to take you advice for the conventional way (that everybody at the university office can understand) to call what I need.

Comment: Talk to them. I'm sure you can explain what you want.

Comment: In USA, many schools call this "Verification of enrollment" (VOE)

Comment: In the U.S., often "transcript" is the document shows the courses you've taken and the grades you received, whether or not you obtained a degree. If you completed even a single course (in the U.S.) the university/college can send "official transcripts" to other institutions to prove what you've done.

Comment: They didn't ask for transcript but for confirmation that I was studied there. They don't care about the marks.

Comment: Also see here (the people there sent me to ask here): https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/134366/does-study-confirmation-works-for-my-purpose?noredirect=1#comment272030_134366

Comment: @UbiquitousStudent What answer are you waiting for that you haven't already gotten here or there?

Answer (score 3):

I once had to acquire a "Certificate of Matriculation" or "Confirmation of Matriculation," similar to what is described here: http://www.ed.ac.uk/student-administration/order-documents/matric-certificate.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is not a single standard name for this document (I am assuming you are asking for its name in English - if not you should probably specify a language), as all the comments show, but there are some simple phrases that would convey what you are asking - it isn't necessary that you know exactly the name for the document at your institution. Also, what you are asking for isn't that special, the university should understand what you need.

I would suggest you simply request "**proof of enrollment**."

Note that your university might have some automated process for producing such documentation, for example at my current institution there is a process for "enrollment verification" [here](https://registrar.wisc.edu/enrollment_verification_acad_rec.htm), and a particular email address to contact if you need the verification mailed or sent in a more official way than obtaining a pdf.

A web search for your institution plus "proof of enrollment" should direct you to something similar for your institution - I tested it on several US and UK universities and all gave me the necessary information on the first or second result returned.